# How to make POST request using retrofit to server in android

Tags: java, android, node.js, retrofit

I am making a POST request using retrofit in android to a server which i have created in Node.js. I have already worked on GET request and it is working fine but when i am making a post request i am not able to get the data.

My Code are as follows:
**DataService.java**

```
public class DataService extends Service{
  private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        try {           
            computeDistance(startLocation);           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stopSelf(msg.arg1);
    }

 public void computeDistance(String endLocation){
       RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Constants.Http.URL_BASE)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();

        ApiService cityService = restAdapter.create(ApiService.class);
        cityService.updateCityData();
    }
  }
}
```

I defined the interface like:
**ApiService.java**

```
public interface ApiService {

    @POST("/city/update")
    public String updateCityData();
}
```

My Node.js file is like:

```
function updateDBData(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Entered into the UpdateDBDATa');
    var sapi = {"data": "false"};
    res.send(200, sapi).end();
}

/**-------- creating a server --------**/
var server = restify.createServer({name: 'crunchbase'});
server.get('/city/:name', updateDBData);
/**------- server listening port -------**/
server.listen(appContext.port, function () {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

When i am invoking the Node.js server with
http://www.api.com:8084/search/update
I am getting the message printed on the console. But when i am making retrofit request through android I am getting error like

```
  D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 405 http://www.api.com:8084/city/update (439ms)<br>
    D/Retrofit﹕ : HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed<br>
    D/Retrofit﹕ Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5 , Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version<br>
    D/Retrofit﹕ Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET<br>
    D/Retrofit﹕ Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *<br>
    D/Retrofit﹕ {"code":"BadMethod","message":"/city/update does not support POST"}
    D/Retrofit﹕ <--- END HTTP (67-byte body)
```

I am not able to figure what is the error and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem is on server side (you don't support post requests).

Try to support it by putting something like

```
server.post('/city/:name', updateDBData);
```

before

```
server.listen
```

Comment: I put the post thing.. but i am getting the error.. D/Retrofit﹕ {"code":"BadMethod","message":"/city/update does not support POST"}

Comment: It's definitely server side problem, check documentation for restify API: http://mcavage.me/node-restify/

Comment: @anand did you restart the server after making the change?